Connection error between MicroStrategy and IBM DB2 Cloud
I am facing a connection error when trying to connect to IBM DB2 Cloud via MicroStrategy.
(Database error <5>: Connect failed. Error type: Odbc error. Odbc operation attempted: SQLDriverConnect. [08001:7570: on SQLHANDLE] [MicroStrategy][ODBC DB2 Wire Protocol driver]SSL Handshake Failure reason [error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure].
We are currently using IBM IIAS in batch mode, and it is 100% operational with MicroStrategy. The connection model used in the odbc.ini was taken from the odbc.ini.example file.
I am using this model for the DB2 Cloud connection.

[DB2-CLOUD]
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
Driver=/opt/.../MYdb2XX.so
Description=MicroStrategy ODBC Driver for Db2 Wire Protocol
Database=DATABASE
IpAddress=IP_SERVIDOR
TcpPort=PORT
AuthenticationMethod=1
EncryptionMethod=1
EncryptionMode=3
CryptoProtocolVersion=SSLV3, TLSV1, TLSV1.1, TLSV1.2
TrustStore=/opt/.../Cert.pem
TrustStorePassword=
ValidateServerCertificate=1
HostNameInCertificate=HOSTNAME_SERVIDOR
DefaultIsolationLevel=1
DynamicSections=1000
WithHold=1
GrantExecute=1
GrantAuthid=PUBLIC
PackageCollection=NULLID
EnableBatchSupport=1
IANAAppCodePage=106

Tests performed:

Driver MYdb2XX.so and MYdb264.so
TrustStore.pem, TrustStore.crt, TrustStore.jks
Connection test with the database via DBeaver (including the certificates mentioned above)
CryptoProtocolVersion: TLSV1, TLSV1.1, TLSV1.2, and all.


This question is not about programming, it concerns configuration. Better suited to dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2 . Check if the Db2-instance is configured to support only TLSv1.3 , as that's not mentioned in your microstrategy driver config.

Thank you for responding. Sorry, I wasn't aware of the existence of Questions tagged [db2]. Is there any way to move it there? Or should I create it there as well? As for TLSV1.3, it is not supported. I have already tested it as well.
(Database error <5>: Connect failed. Error type: Odbc error. Odbc operation attempted: SQLDriverConnect. [HY000:0: on SQLHANDLE] [MicroStrategy][ODBC DB2 Wire Protocol driver]An invalid crypto protocol version was specified: 'TLSV1.3'. Valid values are: SSLV3, TLSV1, TLSV1.1, TLSV1.2 separated by commas.

Pay attention to the detail:  it is the Db2-server instance that determines the protocols and versions and crypto algorithms that it supports.  You might need to upgrade your microstrategy driver if that specific driver cannot cope with TLSv1.3. Consult with the owner of the Db2-server instance to find out how it is configured. You will not progress until and unless you understand these basic things.

You can create a new question on https:/dba.stackexchange.com  as that is best for configuration matters. You might also need to open a ticket with microstrategy to determine the version of its Db2 wire protocol driver supports TLSv1.3 if and only if the Db2-server is configured to only support that version.
